# Sidebar and dash missing - I can't find the tilde button

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've seen others with the same issue that I am having and I see a potential solution however for some reason in the process my keyboard has changed configuration and the @ Button is no longer <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> but <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>.

I think this now means of can't type the tilde button which is included in the compizconfig solution.

Any help I'd be very grateful.  I've lost my mailbox from the desktop. It's a critical situation.

Ubuntu 14.04 is what I'm using by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`~` means your home directory. So you can use full path to your home directory (i.e. `/home/YOUR_USERNAME` ) in place of `~`.

Also (from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> produces `@`) it sounds like you have (inadvertently) switched to *English UK* keyboard layout or something similar. Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> for `~`. Or switch to *English US* or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us which keyboard map your locale uses ...

Have you tried <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>?

On some QWERTZ keyboards, it gives `~` .